# What is the right way to create tabs and line breaks in PHP when using single quotes?

Tags: php, newline, escaping

Seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a solid answer anywhere.  I'm outputting a ton of HTML and find escaping "s to be error prone and hard to read, but I also want to have my HTML formatted nicely.

Want something like this (though I know this won't worK):

```
echo '<div id="test">\n';
echo '\t<div id="test-sub">\n';
echo '\t</div>\n';
echo '</div>\n';
```

What is one to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason you are so keen on avoiding double quotes?

Comment: Hey Evan. you doesn't look like a simpleton. Why such a lame question? If you want to use \n sequence, you have to use double quotes. But proper solution is to type pure HTML. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @Jasper I can tell you. Because of thousands stupid Stackoverflow answers and hundreds stupid articles from other sites, telling you that double quotes are "slow". Slow, my foot!

Comment: @Jasper, I'm submitting a blog to be hosted on WordPress.com VIP (for a client) and the WordPress coding standards prefer single quotes.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, of course I know about double-quotes, I'm just surprised that there isn't a clean method for HTML formatting, when using singles.  Seems like a matter of preference to me - I don't like intermingling so much HTML and PHP together, others might not like all the \n and \t but I prefer it to the alternative.

Comment: Because singles are not for HTML formatting. Isn't it obvious? Every tool has it's use. Escaping from PHP is such a tool for multi-line HTML blocks.

Comment: How would you feel about something like '<div id="test">'."\n" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you look on [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> Heredoc text behaves just like a
> double-quoted string, without the
> double quotes. This means that quotes
> in a heredoc do not need to be escaped

example of advantage here : http://www.shat.net/php/notes/heredoc.php

Comment: I've tried HEREDOC in the past.  Would look into your info but the link isn't working for me.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to make sure, this works just fine for example (PHP_EOL is a cross Platt form Constant for a new line Char (EndOfLine) ):

```
echo "<div id=\"test\">".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t<div id=\"test-sub\">".PHP_EOL;
echo "\t</div>".PHP_EOL;
echo "</div>".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Yeah, PHP_EOL is one option, though I don't know of a comparable constant for a tab, do you?

Comment: @evanmcd you can make your own constants... And make your code even harder to read.

Comment: @evanmcd I don't think there is one, probably there are no cross-OS issues with \t & @Col. Shrapnel sure, sounds like fun :D

Answer (score -1):

use double quotes

or a multi-line echo string:

```
echo '<div id="test">
    <div id="test-sub">
    </div>
</div>';
```

or templates.

Comment: sorry, @SilentGhost, I must have clicked on downvote without realizing... (FF crashed while I was reading this post). I cannot remove the vote now though, if you edit the answer I will surely remove it.

Answer (score -1):

I make use of a small set of classes I wrote in order to output nicely formatted HTML. If you are interested you can find it [here](http://junk.orderofthehammer.com/tagtree.txt).

To get what you want, I would end up writing something like

```
$mypage = page::blank();
$mypage->opennode('div', 'id="test"');
$mypage->opennode('div', 'id="test-sub"');
$mypage->closenode(2); // div, div
echo $mypage->build_output_strict();
```

Another alternative would be to use a full-fledged template engine, of which there are quite a few.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems even harder to read to me, though.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted - I generally feel that if someone downvotes an answer he should leave a message stating his reason for doing so.